Apps Script create a stamp with last edited sheet name
I have created a "battlesheets" spreadsheet. I would like to display a field to show whose turn it is. Or alternatively, a field that displays who edited the spreadsheet last.
The spreadsheet has two sheets, one labeled "Player1" and the other "Player2".
The idea is that each player is on a different sheet/tab while playing. As soon as an edit is made (in this case, an 'x' is placed in the game field), i'd like a cell (M1) to note which player fired last (or whose turn it is - if that is possible) on both sheets.see screenshot
I unfortunately deleted the script I attempted, but I am using onEdit(e) with a variation of this script:

function timestampIt(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // this will assign the first sheet
  var cell = sheet.getRange('A1');
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(d.getHours() +1);
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();
  user = String(user);
  user = user.replace('@gmail.com', '');
  cell.setValue('Last updated: ' + d.toLocaleString() + ' by ' + user);
}



I didn't understand if when player1 puts an X, the sheet to update is player2. If so, here is a function to be triggered onEdit:
function updateLastEditPlayer(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const player1Sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Player1");
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == "Player1") {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Player2");
    const cell = sheet.getRange("M1");
    let d = new Date();
    d.setHours(d.getHours() + 1);
    let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    user = String(user);
    user = user.replace('@gmail.com', '');
    cell.setValue('Last updated: ' + d.toLocaleString() + ' by ' + user);
  } else if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == "Player2") {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Player1");
    const cell = sheet.getRange("M1");
    let d = new Date();
    d.setHours(d.getHours() + 1);
    let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    user = String(user);
    user = user.replace('@gmail.com', '');
    cell.setValue('Last updated: ' + d.toLocaleString() + ' by ' + user);
  }
}


Log SheetName,user email,row, col,timestamp
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();//active sheet
  const lsh = e.source.getSheets()[0];//log sheet
  lsh.getRange(lsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([[sh.getName(), e.user.getEmail(), e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart, new Date()]]);
}

